# Scraping Amazon Detail Page with Goutte Cuts Off At Comparison Table

Tags: laravel, goutte

I'm trying to scrape Amazon detail page with Goutte in a laravel controller like: ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00YFTHJ9C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YFTHJ9C)) and it seems to cut off the scraping during the "Compare with similar items" section.

Most detail pages load fine, but it seems when this table is on the page, it returns a "200" status code, but cuts off right after the first price td.

```
$link = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00YFTHJ9C";
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $link);
echo $crawler->html();
```

I am trying to access the data that is below this table in the "Product information" section, but can't seem to get to it.

Any help with this one would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Amazon will eventually block you as scraping is against their TOS. 2. I suspect your issue is that some portions of the page are loaded via JavaScript and AJAX calls.

Comment: 1. Sad day :(
2. I tried loading the page with JavaScript turned off in Chrome. It still loads up

Answer (score 1):

you can inspect element the page you are **scraping** then go to the selector you are using , then right click , hover on copy then click COPYXPATH , you can use that in goutte :D

Comment: I can't seem to get that part loaded into the crawler at all. It is not in the object in order to filter it